# Lock the size and position of legend in ggplot

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2, legend

When you zoom or change the width and length of the graphic, the legend automatically changes the size. By having texts and segments added with the annotate the original positions are lost. How can I solve this?

- **Example code:**

```r
    library(reshape2)
    library(dplyr)
    library(ggplot2)
    A <- matrix(c(2 ,   0   ,   0   ,   0   ,   0   ,   2   ,
              0 ,   0   ,   0   ,   0   ,   2   ,   2   ,
              0 ,   0   ,   0   ,   0   ,   3   ,   2   ,
              0 ,   0   ,   0   ,   0   ,   0   ,   6   ,
              2 ,   2   ,   3   ,   5   ,   4   ,   2   ,
              6 ,   4   ,   3   ,   0   ,   0   ,   0   ,
              0 ,   0   ,   3   ,   1   ,   0   ,   0   ,
              0 ,   0   ,   0   ,   2   ,   2   ,   1   ,
              0 ,   0   ,   2   ,   3   ,   0   ,   0   ,
              0 ,   2   ,   2   ,   0   ,   0   ,   0), nrow=10, ncol=6, byrow = T)
    rownames(A) <- paste("x", 1:10, sep="")
    colnames(A) <- paste("y", 1:6, sep="")
    longData <- melt(A)
    longData$Var1 <- factor(longData$Var1, levels=names(sort(rowSums(A),             decreasing = T)))
    longData$Var2 <- factor(longData$Var2, levels=names(sort(colSums(A), decreasing = T)))

    longData<-longData[longData$value!=0,]

    ggplot(longData, aes(x = Var2, y = Var1)) +     geom_raster(aes(fill=value)) + 
    scale_fill_gradientn(colours=c("#180052", "#0c0083","#0000b4",     "#0000e4","#0010ff", "#0041ff", "#0072ff", "#00A3FF", "#00D4FF", "#00FF49", "#5AFF00", "#FFE400", "#FFC400", "#FFA300", "#FF8300", "#FF6200", "#FF4100", "#FF2100", "#FF0000", "#E40000"), 
                         values=c(0, 0.05, 0.1, 0.15, 0.2, 0.25, 0.3, 0.35, 0.4, 0.45, 0.5, 0.55, 0.6, 0.65, 0.7, 0.75, 0.8, 0.85, 0.9, 0.95, 1), breaks=seq(0,1,0.2),  limits=c(0,1), 
                     guide = guide_colorbar(title="Value", title.position = "right", title.hjust = 0.5,  title.theme = element_text(angle = 90, size = 9), barwidth= 2, barheight = 10)) + 
      theme_void() +
      annotate("text", x = c(7.1,7.1), y = c(7,4), label = c("increase", "decrease") , size=4 , angle=90) +
      annotate("segment", x = 7.3, xend = 7.3, y = 5, yend = 2, colour = "black", size=1, alpha=0.6, arrow=arrow()) +
      annotate("segment", x = 7.3, xend = 7.3, y = 6, yend = 9, colour = "black", size=1, alpha=0.6, arrow=arrow())
```

- **Here is the graph with the default resolution:**

[image]

- **Here is the graph with the width 900 and height 755:**

[image]

Comment: good question, but why is this a problem?

Comment: With the legend size variation, the arrows and text added to the graphic are outside the original position. I need to fix the legend position so this does not even occur when increasing the dimensions of the chart.